# How to switch Graphics card in linux? (switchable graphics card)

Tags: linux, graphics-card, switchable-graphics

so I have a HP 15-ay037nc laptop, and it has a graphics card, some sort of *Intel*, with 125MB of memory, and an *AMD RX460* with 2GB of memory. In Linux, it uses that intel graphics card, so my games are lagging (I know Linux isn't meant for gaming, but when Warcraft 3 is lagging, that's bad).

So I wonder, how do I switch the graphic cards?